# Select all rows with the MAX value in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, max

Say I have a table `drafts` like the following, where `sent_for_review` is boolean:

```
  rowid | title  |  author  | sent_for_review 
 -------|--------|----------|----------------- 
      1 | Draft1 | John Doe |               0 
      2 | Draft2 | John Doe |               0 
      3 | Draft3 | John Doe |               1 
      4 | Draft4 | John Doe |               1
```

I want to select all drafts that have been sent for review. If there are none, then I want to select all drafts that have not been sent for review.

I tried the following, to try to group by `sent_for_review` and then selecting just the highest one:

```sql
FROM drafts SELECT title WHERE author='John Doe'
GROUP BY sent_for_review HAVING MAX(sent_for_review)
```

But this only returns Draft3 when Draft3 and Draft4 exist (it should return both)... and doesn't return anything when only Draft1 and Draft2 exist (it should return both).

How can I make it return all maximum values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
select * from drafts
where 
  author='John Doe' and
  sent_for_review = (select max(sent_for_review) from drafts where author='John Doe')
```

This query:

```
select max(sent_for_review) from drafts where author='John Doe'
```

will return:
`1` if there are drafts sent for review and
`0` if there are not

Answer (score 2):

You could use windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY author ORDER BY sent_for_review DESC) dr
  FROM drafts
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE dr = 1
  AND author='John Doe';
```

**[db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6m99vNFSdp14XW19RojUYu/0)**

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this seems unnecessarily complex for my purpose. Is there any advantage to this approach over forpas' response?

Comment: @snazzybouche Of course, what if you have more than one author and you want to get drafts for all of them? With accepted answer you have to adjust it to use correlated subquery with my answer you only comment out `author='John Doe'`

Comment: @snazzybouche Give it a try and add another author like: [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/icvFFz2j49bSV52oZwqJ2Z/0)

Comment: I see! I'll leave forpas' response marked as the answer as it's likely more useful for beginners looking for the answer to this problem, but this is definitely a much more robust solution for the situation presented. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is another way to get the same functionality as Lukasz's answer (which is more correct functionally than the accepted answer) but with a simpler query.

```
create table drafts (title,author,sent_for_review);
insert into drafts values
  ('Draft1','Other Author',0),
  ('Draft2','Other Author',2),
  ('Draft1','John Doe',0),
  ('Draft2','John Doe',0),
  ('Draft3','John Doe',1),
  ('Draft4','John Doe',1);

select rowid,* from drafts a
  where sent_for_review = (select max(sent_for_review)
                            from drafts
                            where author = a.author
                            group by author)
    --and author='John Doe'   --uncomment as needed
    ;
```